# Signed apk shows a black screen, while debug version shows just fine?

Tags: java, android

Working with debug build variant, my app works just fine. However, when I sign the app and install it, it starts with a black screen. This is what I have in build.gradle:

```
buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled true debuggable false proguardFiles ...
```

Comment: Hi! I don't think just this information is enough to help you out. Can you produce a minimal app that has this same problem, or describe the steps to reproduce the problem?  And btw, you can mark code as code, so it is displayed more nicely. I edited the code block - you can click "edit" to see how that was done

Comment: Very often the problem is with proguard. Some class not found that the app is swallowing? Anyway you need to provide more info